# How to to merge duplicate entries from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I create a multidimensional array to create a commisioning list from the data later on. For this I have to double entries together and increase the number accordingly.
The origin array is structured as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 272050402526
            [bezeichnung] => Tom Cococha Kokoskohle Coco Gold Shishakohle Naturkohle Shisha Kohle Würfel 1 Kg
            [stueckzahl] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 281881151709
            [bezeichnung] => Tom Cococha - Naturkohle Grün 1 kg
            [stueckzahl] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 281653408911
            [bezeichnung] => 50 actiTube SLIM Aktivkohlefilter Aktivkohle Filter Tune Kohle Slimfilter (7 mm)
            [stueckzahl] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 281881151709
            [bezeichnung] => Tom Cococha - Naturkohle Grün 1 kg
            [stueckzahl] => 1
        )

)
```

Now I would like to merge duplicate entries and merge the number accordingly. My unsuccessful approach was as follows:

```
$secarr = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 0){
                array_push($secarr, $value);
            }else{
                foreach ($secarr as $seckey => $secvalue) {
                    if(in_array($value['bezeichnung'], $secvalue) == TRUE){
                        $secarr[$seckey]['stueckzahl'] = $secvalue['stueckzahl'] + $value['stueckzahl'];
                        continue 2;
                    }else{
                        array_push($secarr, $value);
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The output should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 272050402526
            [bezeichnung] => Tom Cococha Kokoskohle Coco Gold Shishakohle Naturkohle Shisha Kohle Würfel 1 Kg
            [stueckzahl] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 281881151709
            [bezeichnung] => Tom Cococha - Naturkohle Grün 1 kg
            [stueckzahl] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 281653408911
            [bezeichnung] => 50 actiTube SLIM Aktivkohlefilter Aktivkohle Filter Tune Kohle Slimfilter (7 mm)
            [stueckzahl] => 1
        )
)
```

Can someone help me?

Best regards,
Pascal

Comment: What have you tried? What was the problem? Can you describe the algorithm you want to implement in human language?

Comment: In the first loop, I went through the original array. If the pointer was set to 0 I wrote the content into a second array. If this was not the case, I went through the second array with a second loop and checked if the same value "label" is already in the second array. If so, he should take from both the number of pieces and adapt it in the second array. If the record is not in the second array, it should be added to it.

Comment: If that's supposed to describe the algorithm in human language, then you failed. For example, what is a pointer, a loop, an array? Start with "For every order in the input list, do ..." (you don't write it explicitly, but I'm assuming these are orders).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.

```
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['id'], $output)) {
        $output[$item['id']]['stueckzahl'] += $item['stueckzahl'];
    } else {
        $output[$item['id']] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

You can run it online here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4cd9a253538931250867099305c9741c83c2e52f

Edited in response to Jeff's input. He's probably right; that's more likely to be what you're after.

Comment: the only thing I'd change in your answer is to _not_ hardcode the stueckzahl, but actually use `$item['stueckzahl']` to be added.